# How to Create Records from XML Data?

Tags: apex, xml, httpresponse, xmlparsing

This is the webservice response I am Getting in XML Format.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<ListOrdersResponse xmlns="https://mws.amazonservices.com/Orders/2013-09-01">
  <ListOrdersResult>
    <Orders>
      <Order>
        <LatestShipDate>2016-05-04T11:44:15Z</LatestShipDate>
        <OrderType>StandardOrder</OrderType>
        <PurchaseDate>2016-05-04T04:59:42Z</PurchaseDate>
        <BuyerEmail>abc@marketplace.amazon.in</BuyerEmail>
        <AmazonOrderId>402-1183244-123344</AmazonOrderId>
        <LastUpdateDate>2016-05-04T11:45:13Z</LastUpdateDate>
        <NumberOfItemsShipped>1</NumberOfItemsShipped>
        <ShipServiceLevel>Standard</ShipServiceLevel>
        <OrderStatus>Shipped</OrderStatus>
        <SalesChannel>Amazon.in</SalesChannel>
        <NumberOfItemsUnshipped>0</NumberOfItemsUnshipped>
        <BuyerName>AAAAAA</BuyerName>
        <OrderTotal>
          <CurrencyCode>INR</CurrencyCode>
          <Amount>55555</Amount>
        </OrderTotal>
        <IsPremiumOrder>false</IsPremiumOrder>
        <EarliestShipDate>2016-05-04T11:44:15Z</EarliestShipDate>
        <MarketplaceId>qwerty</MarketplaceId>
        <FulfillmentChannel>AFN</FulfillmentChannel>
        <PaymentMethod>Other</PaymentMethod>
        <ShippingAddress>
          <StateOrRegion>abc</StateOrRegion>
          <City>aaaa</City>
          <Phone>1234567890</Phone>
          <CountryCode>IN</CountryCode>
          <PostalCode>1234</PostalCode>
          <Name>zxcvb</Name>
          <AddressLine1>poiu</AddressLine1>
          <AddressLine2>lkjh</AddressLine2>
        </ShippingAddress>
        <IsPrime>false</IsPrime>
        <ShipmentServiceLevelCategory>Standard</ShipmentServiceLevelCategory>
        <SellerOrderId>25652-25689-25698</SellerOrderId>
      </Order>
      <Order>
        <LatestShipDate>2016-05-04T11:44:15Z</LatestShipDate>
        <OrderType>StandardOrder</OrderType>
        <PurchaseDate>2016-05-04T04:59:42Z</PurchaseDate>
        <BuyerEmail>abc@marketplace.amazon.in</BuyerEmail>
        <AmazonOrderId>402-1183244-123344</AmazonOrderId>
        <LastUpdateDate>2016-05-04T11:45:13Z</LastUpdateDate>
        <NumberOfItemsShipped>1</NumberOfItemsShipped>
        <ShipServiceLevel>Standard</ShipServiceLevel>
        <OrderStatus>Shipped</OrderStatus>
        <SalesChannel>Amazon.in</SalesChannel>
        <NumberOfItemsUnshipped>0</NumberOfItemsUnshipped>
        <BuyerName>AAAAAA</BuyerName>
        <OrderTotal>
          <CurrencyCode>INR</CurrencyCode>
          <Amount>55555</Amount>
        </OrderTotal>
        <IsPremiumOrder>false</IsPremiumOrder>
        <EarliestShipDate>2016-05-04T11:44:15Z</EarliestShipDate>
        <MarketplaceId>qwerty</MarketplaceId>
        <FulfillmentChannel>AFN</FulfillmentChannel>
        <PaymentMethod>Other</PaymentMethod>
        <ShippingAddress>
          <StateOrRegion>abc</StateOrRegion>
          <City>aaaa</City>
          <Phone>1234567890</Phone>
          <CountryCode>IN</CountryCode>
          <PostalCode>1234</PostalCode>
          <Name>zxcvb</Name>
          <AddressLine1>poiu</AddressLine1>
          <AddressLine2>lkjh</AddressLine2>
        </ShippingAddress>
        <IsPrime>false</IsPrime>
        <ShipmentServiceLevelCategory>Standard</ShipmentServiceLevelCategory>
        <SellerOrderId>25652-25689-25698</SellerOrderId>
      </Order>
 </Orders>
    <CreatedBefore>2016-05-04T05:30:00Z</CreatedBefore>
  </ListOrdersResult>
  <ResponseMetadata>
    <RequestId>123564-25416-49df-2565-36524155</RequestId>
  </ResponseMetadata>
</ListOrdersResponse>
```

I want to create a Order Records but to Parse This XML

**`string output_result = res.getBody();`**

I've tried
**Option A**

```
public class Parser_New{

    public class MonthlyReport {
        public String LatestShipDate {get; set;}
        public String OrderType {get; set;}
        public String PurchaseDate {get; set;}
    }

    public List<MonthlyReport> parse(string toParse) {
        List<MonthlyReport> reports = new List<MonthlyReport>();
        DOM.Document doc = new DOM.Document();
        doc.load(toParse);    
        parseReports(doc.getRootElement(), reports);

        system.debug('DDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDD'+ Reports);
        return reports;
    }

    private void parseReports(DOM.XMLNode node, List<MonthlyReport> reports) {
        for (Dom.XMLNode child : node.getChildElements()) {
            if (child.getName() == 'Order') {
                MonthlyReport r = new MonthlyReport();
                parseReport(child, r);
                reports.add(r);
            }
        }
    }

    private void parseReport(DOM.XMLNode node, MonthlyReport r) {
        for (Dom.XMLNode child : node.getChildElements()) {
            if (child.getName() == 'LatestShipDate') {
                r.LatestShipDate= child.getText().trim();
            } else if (child.getName() == 'OrderType') {
                r.OrderType= child.getText().trim();
            } else if (child.getName() == 'PurchaseDate') {
                r.PurchaseDate= child.getText().trim();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

But I am not Getting any Result in the **p.parse(output_result);**

**OPTION B**

```
 Public String walkThrough(DOM.XMLNode node) {
        String result = '\n';
        if (node.getNodeType() == DOM.XMLNodeType.COMMENT) {
            return 'Comment (' +  node.getText() + ')';
        }
        if (node.getNodeType() == DOM.XMLNodeType.TEXT) {
            return 'Text (' + node.getText() + ')';
        }
        if (node.getNodeType() == DOM.XMLNodeType.ELEMENT) {

            if (node.getText().trim() != '') {
                outxmlstring += node.getName()+'=' +node.getText().trim()+'\n';
                String nName = node.getName();

            }
            if (node.getAttributeCount() > 0) { 
                for (Integer i = 0; i< node.getAttributeCount(); i++ ) {
                    result += ', attribute #' + i + ':' + node.getAttributeKeyAt(i) + '=' + node.getAttributeValue(node.getAttributeKeyAt(i), node.getAttributeKeyNsAt(i));
                }  
            }
            for (Dom.XMLNode child: node.getChildElements()) {
                result += walkThrough(child);
            }
            return result;
        }
        return '';
    }
```

Above method invoking like 
**String Resultt = walkThrough(L1);**

Where L1 is

**Dom.XMLNode L1 = docx.getRootElement();**

In both the Options I am Not result.
So..Is it a correct way or there is a error in Code ??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like you are close with 'Option A'.

The issue you're running into is that you're not getting deep enough into your XML hierarchy before trying to look for individual orders.

Given your input XML (I'm abbreviating it)

```
<ListOrdersResponse xmlns="https://mws.amazonservices.com/Orders/2013-09-01">
  <ListOrdersResult>
    <Orders>
      <Order>
        ...
      </Order>
      ...
    </Orders>
  </ListOrdersResult>
</ListOrdersResponse>
```

When you call `doc.getRootElement()`, you're being placed at `<ListOrdersResponse>` node in your XML tree.

When you pass that to your `parse()` method, you call `getChildElements()`, which gets you to the `<ListOrdersResult>` node.

As 'ListOrdersResult' != 'Order', and `ListOrdersResult` is the only (direct) child of the document root, you don't execute the code in the if block, and you exit the loop.

The minimal modification needed to get your code working would be to traverse two more levels down the XML tree sometime before you check `if (child.getName() == 'Order')`

You can do this either before you call, or inside of, `parseReports()`. My preference would be to do this prior to the call.

```
public List<MonthlyReport> parse(string toParse) {
    List<MonthlyReport> reports = new List<MonthlyReport>();
    DOM.Document doc = new DOM.Document();
    doc.load(toParse);

    // Puts us at the <ListOrdersResponse> node;
    Dom.XmlNode root = doc.getRootElement();

    // Puts us at the <ListOrdersResult> node
    List<Dom.XmlNode> listOrdersResult = root.getChildElements();

    // Puts us at the <Orders> node. If we call getChildElements() on one of these, 
    //  we will get all of the <Order> nodes.
    List<Dom.XmlNode> orders = listOrdersResult[0].getChildElements(); 

    parseReports(orders[0], reports);

    system.debug('DDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDD'+ Reports);
    return reports;
}

private void parseReports(DOM.XMLNode node, List<MonthlyReport> reports) {
    for (Dom.XMLNode child : node.getChildElements()) {
        if (child.getName() == 'Order') {
            MonthlyReport r = new MonthlyReport();
            parseReport(child, r);
            reports.add(r);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: @ Derek .Worked like a charm..